# Cassandra - Query a column with collection type

Tags: cassandra

I am pretty new to cassandra, so pardon me if this turns out to be a silly question.

I have a table structure as below

```
CREATE TABLE data_points (
  id text PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at timestamp,
  previous_event_id varchar,
  properties map<text,text>
);
```

I wanted to know, whether I can execute a query which gives matching records from the `map` type fields.

For instance, if I insert values in the table as below

```
INSERT INTO datapoints (id, properties) VALUES ('1', { 'fruit' : 'apple', 'band' : 'Beatles' });
```

Will I be able to fetch it as

`SELECT * from data_points WHERE properties.band='Beatles';`

Please Help.

Comment: [The only manual I've found so far](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#collections) doesn't seem to provide a direct answer to this, but perhaps this syntax would work: `SELECT * from data_points WHERE properties['band'] = 'Beatles';`?

Comment: I tried this @AndriyM , but got the following error `Bad Request: line 1:44 no viable alternative at input '['`

Answer (score 17):

You can index collection types in [cassandra 2.1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4511) and later. You are after:

`SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <field> CONTAINS <value_in_list/map/set>`

Detailed example:

```
cqlsh> USE ks;
cqlsh:ks> CREATE TABLE data_points (
            id text PRIMARY KEY,
            created_at timestamp,
            previous_event_id varchar,
            properties map<text,text>
         );
cqlsh:ks> create index on data_points (properties);
cqlsh:ks> INSERT INTO data_points (id, properties) VALUES ('1', { 'fruit' : 'apple', 'band' : 'Beatles' });
cqlsh:ks> INSERT INTO data_points (id, properties) VALUES ('2', { 'fruit' : 'cherry', 'band' : 'Beatles' });
cqlsh:ks> SELECT * FROM data_points WHERE properties CONTAINS 'Beatles';

 id | created_at | previous_event_id | properties
----+------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------
  2 |       null |              null | {'band': 'Beatles', 'fruit': 'cherry'}
  1 |       null |              null |  {'band': 'Beatles', 'fruit': 'apple'}

(2 rows)
```

Word of warning, secondary indexes don't scale out well as they use a scatter/gather algorithm to find what you need, if you plan to use them for heavy tagging it might be better to denormalize the `properties` field int a separate table and carry out multiple queries.

Further reading:

- [Is it possible to use cql to query collections in a row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873959/is-it-possible-to-use-cql-to-query-collections-in-a-row/21881585)

Comment: @Lyuben I won't be able to test this answer at the moment. So just an upvote for now :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case of a map (or set/list), apparently, "Partial reads of collection columns are not possible in CQL. The only way to retrieve data from a collection is to read the collection in its entirety".

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024839/select-specific-value-from-map

However, if your query is setting, updating or removing, they work fine.